# Python 2.7: find item in list ignoring case

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of strings

```
["oranges", "POTATOES", "Pencils", "PAper"]
```

I want to find whether the list contains `paper`, ignoring case; so that the following code snippet should print `found`. My list only contains simple strings constituted of only the English alphabet -- upper and lower cases.

```
item = 'paper'
stuff = ["oranges", "POTATOES", "Pencils", "PAper"]
if item in stuff:
    print "found"
else:
   print "Not found"

#How do I get the method to print "found"?
```

CLARIFICATION:

My list is actually a list of lists and my logic is using the following construct:

```
if not any ( item in x for x in stuff):
   print "Not found"
else:
   print "found"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd combine `lower` with `any`:

```
>>> stuff = ["oranges", "POTATOES", "Pencils", "PAper"]
>>> any(s.lower() == 'paper' for s in stuff)
True
>>> any(s.lower() == 'paperclip' for s in stuff)
False
```

This will short-circuit and stop searching as soon as it finds one (unlike a listcomp).  OTOH, if you're going to be doing multiple searches, then you might as well use a listcomp to lower the whole list once.

For your updated case (why is it that no one ever asks the question they're interested in, but a different question instead?), I'd probably do something like

```
>>> any("book" in (s.lower() for s in x) for x in stuff)
True
>>> any("paper" in (s.lower() for s in x) for x in stuff)
True
>>> any("stuff" in (s.lower() for s in x) for x in stuff)
False
```

The same rule holds, though.  If you're doing multiple searches, you're probably better off canonicalizing the list-of-lists once.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the elegant response!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) to convert the list to lowercase.

```
if item in [x.lower() for x in stuff]:
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

> > > > stuff = ["oranges", "POTATOES", "Pencils", "PAper"]
> > > >         print [x.lower() for x in stuff]
> > > >         ['oranges', 'potatoes', 'pencils', 'paper']

Answer (score 1):

Convert both strings to either upper case or lower case and compare them?

```
item = 'paper'
stuff = ["oranges", "POTATOES", "Pencils", "PAper"]
if item.upper() in map(lambda x: x.upper(), stuff):
    print "found"
else:
    print "Not found"
```

Extra:
Then use this line

```
if not any ( item.upper() in map(lambda y: y.upper(), x) for x in stuff):
```

Answer (score 1):

not a python buff and in general new to programming, but well, here is my solution:

I tried to stay close to your general approach, however you might want to look into encapsulating the code within a function.

I don't know about your level of experience, so please pardon if I'm posting something that you already are familiar with

Here some general information on functions: 
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28computer_science%29)

Here Pythons documentation on functions:
[Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

First solution, verbose but more understandable for someone new to this:

```
def item_finder_a(item, stuff):
    new_array = []
    for w in stuff:
        new_array.append(w.lower())
    if item in new_array:
        print "found"
    else:
       print "Not found"

item_finder(word,array_of_words)
```

And the slightly shorter more concise version

```
def item_finder_b(item, stuff):
    if item in map(str.lower,stuff):
        print "found"
    else:
       print "Not found"

item_finder_b(word,array_of_words)
```

Hope this helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using what you have now you could use the `lower` function.

```
for strings in stuff:
  if strings.lower() == item:
    print "found"

print "Not found"
```